# Object-C : Why tableView can not respond any event after i deleted a cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, ipad

I make views like this: `myController.view.aView.scrollView.tableView`.

The problem occurs after i do:

D_1. try to delete a row. // by `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

D_2. dataSource delete one data.

D_3. do something with dataSource.

D_4. [tableView relaodData].//it is working in main thread.

It's the problem :

P_1. The tableView can not scroll.

P_2. The tableView do not perform any delegate method.

P_3. The views in cell, do not respond any events.

I try this :

T_1.  Replace (D_4)`[tableView relaodData]` with `[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone]`
.
No problem occured, but i must make tableView reloadData.

T_2.  Add this code in aView:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UIView *getView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
debugLog(@"hit test get view : %@", getView);
return getView;
}
```

It get views normal. But the views do not respond any events.

I think that some problem happened when i do [tableView reloadData]. But i can't find it.

Append on :

1. tableView init :

   ```
   self.tableView                    = [UITableView new];
   self.tableView.dataSource         = self.tableDataSource;
   self.tableView.delegate           = self.tableDelegate;
   self.tableView.bounces            = NO;
   self.tableView.separatorStyle     = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
   self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 55;
   self.tableView.rowHeight          = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;


   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
   if (!cell) {
       cell = [ACellClass newWithParameters:...];
   }
   [cell clear];
   [self updateCell:cell withIndexPath:indexPath];
   return cell;
   }
   ```
2. I make AView (aView.scrollView.tableView) as a custom view, and the tableView.delegate, tableView.dataSource is myController. The aView is new in `[myController viewWillAppear:animated]`.
3. delete cell with delegate:

   ```
   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
      if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        //delete data with index : indexPath.row.
        [tableView reloadData];
      }
    }
   ```
4. I did some data operation in D_3.

Comment: Could you provide some code what will show:
- how do you init your tableView
- how do you populate tableView
- how do you delete data from dataSource
- and what are you doing on this step D_3. do something with dataSource.
?

Comment: I add the info at bottom.

Comment: What are doing on UISwipeGestureRecognizer? Could you provide code?

Comment: I made a mistake, it looks not a UISwipeGestureRecognizer. I delete a row with delegate method `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`.
It takes no space in the cell.  I also tried to delete one data by a button , and reload tableView after. It works good.

Comment: If there is any way to solve the problem, i would rather delete a data by delegate method.